# How can i get cookie value in YII framework?

Tags: yii

In login module,  I create cookie for that in controller.  I can validate cookie exist. I follow YII framework but it has error when i get cookie. Here is error:

**Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$username = Yii::app()->request->cookies['loginSuccess']->value;
```

here is I create cookie:

```
if($model->validate() && $model->login()){          
    $cookie = new CHttpCookie('loginSuccess',$model->username);
    $cookie->expire = 604800;                           
    Yii::app()->request->cookies['loginSuccess'] = $cookie;
    $this->redirect('/ktbeauty/index.php/categories/index');
}
```

I var_dump cookie before redirect it show like this:

```
    object(CHttpCookie)#37 (9) 
    { 
            ["name"]=> string(12) 
            "loginSuccess" ["value"]=> string(7) 
            "sacpv04" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["expire"]=> int(604800) 
            ["path"]=>string(1) "/" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httpOnly"]=> bool(false) 
            ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL 
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you setting cookie before access? If not, check the cookie exist or not with use of `isset` function.

Comment: Are you trying to read the cookie within the same request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$cookie->expire = time() + 604800;
```

This expression sets the cookie to expire after 604800  from the current time.
This will work for you :)

Comment: yes,it work for me,thankyou very much,in any ways, can you introduce to me all properties of cookie? the most importance that the cookie security thankyou again